# Generate single file with HTMLTestRunner when running multiple test classes

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I'm trying to configure the HTMLTestRunner to output to a single file when multiple test classes are being called, but after much reading I've been unable to achieve this.

An example of what I'm doing is:

```
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one_is_one(self):
        one = 1
        self.assertEqual(1, one)


class TestTwo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_two_is_two(self):
        two = 2
        self.assertEqual(2, two)
```

I'm then adding these into a test suite and running the HTMLTestRunner as below:

```
output = 'C:\\Reports\TestReport.html'

test_suite = unittest.TestSuite(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(Tests))
runner = HTMLTestRunner(output=output)
runner.run(test_suite)
```

However when running like this I'm getting two HTML files generated, one for TestOne and another for TestTwo.

I've looked around and other examples of this I've come across use:

```
with open(output, 'wb') as o:
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(output=o)
    runner.run(test_suite)
```

However this doesn't appear to be supported anymore by HTMLTestRunner.

Is what I'm after possible?

I really like the reports generated, however I don't really want to have to deal with lots of small HTML files that need to be either merged together or viewed separately.

Additional info:
I'm using Python 3.5 with HTMLTestRunner 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old ticket, but thought it was worth sharing the following information.

I wanted to do the same as the original question, a single HTML report for the entire test suite. In the latest version of HtmlTestRunner (installed using `pip install html-testRunner`), the following option is available:

`combine_test_reports=True`.

Which can be used as follows:

```
html_runner = HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
              stream=output_file,
              combine_reports=True,
              report_title='HTML test runner report')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lw246,

I see two htmltestrunners. the 1.0.3 version you used seems to be different, and is still in beta version. The author calls it html-testrunner with a '-'

The original htmlrunner of tungwaiyip is called 'htmltestrunner' without the '-' , and it has been forked with new version. you can see it here: https://github.com/dash0002/HTMLTestRunner.

You can also see the 2 different htmltestrunners here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=htmltestrunner&submit=search

In addition, there is also an htmltestrunner2   :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. There's so many test runners floating around it'd seem!
In the end I resorted to using the XMLTestRunner and writing my own module to parse the results and output them to a database which is read by a simple webpage. Seems to be doing the trick so far :-)